# Etimología de la palabra "úchale"

Tags: etimología

La palabra **úchale** tiene el siguiente significado de acuerdo al [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/)

**¡úchale!**

> I. 1.  Mx. ¡újule! pop + cult → espon.

**¡újule!**

> 1.interj. Mx, Gu. Expresa decepción o desaliento ante algo que se ha dicho.
> 2. Mx, ES. Expresa admiración, sorpresa o dificultad. pop. (¡hújule!; ¡úchale!).
> a. ǁ    ¡~ julita! loc. interj. Mx. Expresa burla, sorpresa, decepción o desaliento. pop.

Pero quisiera saber la etimología de la palabra.

PS. No estoy solo: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Gabee_Chan/status/1279207003340935168)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Úchale
Sinónimo: Hújule.

> De újule, con influencia de la grafía para híjole.

[https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/hújule](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%BAjule)

Hijole:

> "Hijo" probablemente es acortamiento de "hijo de puta", o sus variantes. -le no funciona aquí exactamente como un pronombre enclítico, sino más bien un elemento compositivo.

https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/hijole

Comment: So *hijo de puta → hijo de' → híjole →(h)újule →uchale*